# NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/RestAssured Error is occured

Tags: java, rest, automation, rest-assured

I have imported all the required jars to run RestAssured program. But facing this error.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
```

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
public class bascis {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://rahulshettyacademy.com";
        given().log().all().queryParam("key", "qaclick123").header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .body("{\r\n"
                + "  \"location\": {\r\n"
                + "    \"lat\": -38.383494,\r\n"
                + "    \"lng\": 33.427362\r\n"
                + "  },\r\n"
                + "  \"accuracy\": 50,\r\n"
                + "  \"name\": \"Frontline house\",\r\n"
                + "  \"phone_number\": \"(+91) 983 893 3937\",\r\n"
                + "  \"address\": \"29, side layout, cohen 09\",\r\n"
                + "  \"types\": [\r\n"
                + "    \"shoe park\",\r\n"
                + "    \"shop\"\r\n"
                + "  ],\r\n"
                + "  \"website\": \"http://google.com\",\r\n"
                + "  \"language\": \"French-IN\"\r\n"
                + "}\r\n"
                + "\r\n"
                + "").when().post("maps/api/place/add/json").then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
   }

}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you manage your imports? Maven? Gradle? Imported .jar files into the project? This error indicates you are missing a dependency

Answer (score 1):

Why not use maven to solve this dependency problem ?, if you want you can use the following steps, its fairly easy.

1. Create a maven project
2. Add pom.xml at the root folder
3. Add the following in your pom.xml for the rest assured dependency

> ```
> <dependency>
>       <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
>       <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
>       <version>4.4.0</version>
>       <scope>test</scope>
> </dependency>
> ```

4. After this run

> mvn clean install

5. Use the same program and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven Project and paste io.restassured dependency in pom.xml.

maven project steps:
1.The first step is to open Eclipse, which comes with the integrated Maven environment. For this demo, we are using the Oxygen version of eclipse.

After opening Eclipse, choose the workspace you want to use.

2.Go to the File option
3.In the drop-down menu, select New
4.Select the Project option
5.Select the Maven Project option
6.Click on Next
A dialog box will appear. Select the default workspace.
7.Click on “Next”
Several Group IDs, Artifact IDs, and Versions will then appear.
In the next dialog box that appears, you’ll complete the following steps:

8.Enter the Group ID
“com.testRestAssured”

9.Enter the Artifact ID
“mavenproject”
The version will appear on the screen
These items can all be modified at a later time if needed.

10.Click on “Finish”
Select a plugin there and click on “Next”

The project is now created.

1.Open the pom.xml file
Paste bellow snippet

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version> // Latest Dependency
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured

Answer (score -1):

The rest assured library was created to be used in the test scope. You shouldn't use it in main scope.

- src

  - main
  - test <-- correct way

The rest assured library must be used in the test scope as explained here:
[The import io.restassured.RestAssured cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515714/the-import-io-restassured-restassured-cannot-be-resolved)

I recommend using gradle to manage dependencies.  If you prefer, you can Download this project with the structure with main, test. In addition to gradle and JUnit support: https://github.com/developercancun/gradle-simple

```
git clone https://github.com/developercancun/gradle-simple.git
```

Run from the console in the project directory

```
./gradlew clean build
```

You can see that works here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XVrM.jpg

Comment: You can use Rest Assured in compile and test scope. Instead of `./gradlew clean build` you could simply run `test` phase.